# How do I remove the gap between header and nav?

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove the gap between the `<nav>` element and the `<header>` element. I have tried `margin: 0;` and other things similar to it, but nothing seems to work. I would greatly appreciate someone helping me!

```css
body { 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
header { 
    background-color: #00B386;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/id/542/1000/350);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 400%;
    text-indent: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
} 
h3 {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
nav { 
    background-color: #70DBDB; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
h2 { 
    color: #00664D;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
dt { 
    color: #00664D; 
}
.barn {
    color: #5C7FA3; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
}
nav ul li{ 
    display: inline;
}
nav ul {
    padding-left: 0
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none
}
footer {
    font-size: 75%;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}
dt {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header><h1>Green Pasture Stable and Training</h1></header>
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="board.html">Board</a></li>
        <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <body>
        <h2>A complete horse training & boarding facility</h2>
        <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/584/350/200" alt="rider1"> 
        <p><span class="barn">Green Pasture Stable and Training</span> is a full service training and boarding facility, located in just 20 miles east of Cincinnati in Amelia Ohio.  Whether you show competitively, trail ride, or just need a comfortable safe place for you horse to retire, you and your horse will love it here.</p>
        <ul style="list-style-image: url(marker.gif)">
            <li>Ride year round, regardless of the weather, in our indoor arena.</li>
            <li>Enjoy easy access to miles of trails at East Fork State Park.</li>
            <li>We offer several board and training packages to fit a variety of needs and budgets.</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
<span id="barn">Green Pastures Stable and Training</span><br>
1252 Green Pasture Rd<br>
Amelia, Ohio 45102<br>
<br>
888-555-0751<br><br>
          </div>
    </body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        <footer>
Copyright &copy; 2023 University of Cincinnati IT2040<br>
<a href="example@example.com">example@example.com</a>
        </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every element has default styling, in your case  is the reason for the margin between HEADER and NAV.

`<ul>` has a default margin top and bottom of *1rem (16px)*. So, to remove the gap in your case you can use a **margin:0 for `ul` tag** in css file.

Add (`ul {margin:0;}`)  in your css file to fix the issue.

alternatively you can also reset all the default margins and padding by using `* {margin:0; padding:0;}`. So that you can customize all the margins and paddings from scratch.

```css
ul {
  margin:0;
 }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #666666;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
header {
  background-color: #00b386;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-image: url(pasture.png);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 400%;
  text-indent: 1em;
  /* margin-bottom: 0; */
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
h3 {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
nav {
  background-color: #70dbdb;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h2 {
  color: #00664d;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
dt {
  color: #00664d;
}
.barn {
  color: #5c7fa3;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer {
  font-size: 75%;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
}
dt {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Green Pastures</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
        <header><h1>Green Pasture Stable and Training</h1></header>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="board.html">Board</a></li>
            <li><a href="training.html">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <body>
            <h2>A complete horse training & boarding facility</h2>
            <img src="rider1.png" alt="rider1" height="250px" width="320px"> 
            <p><span class="barn">Green Pasture Stable and Training</span> is a full service training and boarding facility, located in just 20 miles east of Cincinnati in Amelia Ohio.  Whether you show competitively, trail ride, or just need a comfortable safe place for you horse to retire, you and your horse will love it here.</p>
            <ul style="list-style-image: url(marker.gif)">
                <li>Ride year round, regardless of the weather, in our indoor arena.</li>
                <li>Enjoy easy access to miles of trails at East Fork State Park.</li>
                <li>We offer several board and training packages to fit a variety of needs and budgets.</li>
              </ul>
              <div>
    <span id="barn">Green Pastures Stable and Training</span><br>
    1252 Green Pasture Rd<br>
    Amelia, Ohio 45102<br>
    <br>
    888-555-0751<br><br>
              </div>
        </body>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
            <footer>
    Copyright &copy; 2023 University of Cincinnati IT2040<br>
    <a href="example@example.com">example@example.com</a>
            </footer>
```

Comment: Actually, there is one thing. I only wanted no spacing between header and nav. Can you send a copy of the code where it only affects header and nav elements? Thanks!

Comment: Check the answer again, it is the 'ul' that is causing the gap in your case, so make the margin for ul elements to 0, where ever you have the issue

Answer (score 0):

The default margin on the `<ul>` element is causing the problem. Why are you using a `<ul>` in a navigation menu? `<ul>` designates a bulleted list. Yes, you can override all its default styling, but why bother?

Modern HTML has a [simple way](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp) to build a perfectly good, semantically correct navigation menu. Just use a `<nav>` element containing `<a>` elements. It has no default styles, so you’re free to style it however you like.

```css
body { 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
header { 
    background-color: #00B386;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/id/542/1000/350);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 400%;
    text-indent: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
} 
h3 {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
nav { 
    background-color: #70DBDB; 
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    display: flex;
    gap: 1em;
}
h2 { 
    color: #00664D;
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
dt { 
    color: #00664D; 
}
.barn {
    color: #5C7FA3; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
}
nav a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer {
    font-size: 75%;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}
dt {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<header><h1>Green Pasture Stable and Training</h1></header>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="board.html">Board</a>
        <a href="training.html">Training</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
    <body>
        <h2>A complete horse training & boarding facility</h2>
        <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/584/350/200" alt="rider1"> 
        <p><span class="barn">Green Pasture Stable and Training</span> is a full service training and boarding facility, located in just 20 miles east of Cincinnati in Amelia Ohio.  Whether you show competitively, trail ride, or just need a comfortable safe place for you horse to retire, you and your horse will love it here.</p>
        <ul style="list-style-image: url(marker.gif)">
            <li>Ride year round, regardless of the weather, in our indoor arena.</li>
            <li>Enjoy easy access to miles of trails at East Fork State Park.</li>
            <li>We offer several board and training packages to fit a variety of needs and budgets.</li>
          </ul>
          <div>
<span id="barn">Green Pastures Stable and Training</span><br>
1252 Green Pasture Rd<br>
Amelia, Ohio 45102<br>
<br>
888-555-0751<br><br>
          </div>
    </body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        <footer>
Copyright &copy; 2023 University of Cincinnati IT2040<br>
<a href="example@example.com">example@example.com</a>
        </footer>
```

Comment: I was following an assignment for my class

Comment: Send your teacher the link in my answer and tell them to get with the times! 